# Special handling of first and/or last item in an etoolbox list

Tags: loops, etoolbox

Is there a simple way of handling the first and/or the last item in an `etoolbox`-based list in a special way? Here’s a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\forcsvlist{\listadd\namelist}{Tom, Dick, Harry, Jack}

\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{; #1}
\dolistloop{\namelist}

\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{#1, }
\dolistloop{\namelist}

\end{document}
```

The output is

> ; Tom; Dick; Harry; Jack
>
> Tom, Dick, Harry, Jack,

How would I go about changing the above code to create the output

> Tom; Dick; Harry; Jack
>
> Tom, Dick, Harry and Jack

The first output would be easy to achieve if one could define the first item’s formatting to be simply `#1` while the rest are formatted as `; #1`. The second output would be easy to achieve if one could define all items to be formatted as `, #1` except the first one, which should be `#1` and the last one, which should be  `and #1`.

Note that I’m looking for a solution for `etoolbox` lists, not other list structures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the first problem, I'd define `\do` to precede the entry with `\process`, whose initial meaning is just to redefine itself to the desired separator:

```
\newcommand{\semicolonlist}[1]{%
  \def\process{\def\process{; }}%
  \def\do##1{\process##1}%
  \dolistloop{#1}}

\semicolonlist\namelist
```

For the second problem, one can process the list once to get the number of elements and then use this information in a second pass:

```
\newcommand{\commaorandlist}[1]{%
  \count255=0
  \def\do##1{\advance\count255 1 \chardef\finalitem=\count255 }%
  \dolistloop{#1}%
  \count255=0
  \def\do##1{\advance\count255 1
    \ifnum\count255=\finalitem
      \space and\space
    \else
      \ifnum\count255=1
      \else
    ,\space
      \fi
    \fi##1}
  \dolistloop{#1}}

\commaorandlist\namelist
```

These commands *print* the list; if you need to use them in an expandable context you can do, say for `\commaorandlist`,

```
\newcommand{\xcommaorandlist}[2]{%
  \count255=0
  \def\do##1{\advance\count255 1 \chardef\finalitem=\count255 }%
  \dolistloop{#1}%
  \count255=0
  \toks0={}% 
  \def\do##1{\advance\count255 1
    \edef\next{%
      \ifnum\count255=\finalitem
    \space and\space
      \else
        \ifnum\count255=1
        \else
          ,\space
        \fi
      \fi
    }
    \toks2={##1}%

    \edef\next{\the\toks0 \next \the\toks2}%
    \toks0=\expandafter{\next}%
  }%
  \dolistloop{#1}%
  \edef#2{\the\toks0 }%
}
```

and then call

```
\xcommaorandlist\namelist\finallist
\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\finallist}}
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work perfectly. This might really be a new question, but is there an easy way to also define the result as a fully expanded macro? I’m trying to use it to set the `pdfauthor` in `\hypersetup`, which doesn’t work.

Comment: @KarlOveHufthammer See edited answer

Comment: Wow! That looks complicated, but works perfectly. Thanks! I’m currently reading the *TeXbook* and *TeX by Topic*, hoping to some day being able to understand that code. :)

Answer (score 9):

here a simple solution which also counts the lists and the counter is used to locate the last element inside the list:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{elementcount}
\forcsvlist{\stepcounter{elementcount}\listadd\namelist}{Tom, Dick, Harry, Jack}

\number\value{elementcount}:
\def\do#1{%
 \ifnumequal{\value{elementcount}}{1}{%
  #1}{\addtocounter{elementcount}{-1}#1,~}%   
}
\dolistloop{\namelist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I accepted egreg’s answer, but I also like this one very much, as it’s easy to see how to modify it to handle special-casing of different items than the first or last one.

Comment: A second counter is needed if you want to use the loop multiple times. `elementcount` should be copied to the second counter before the loop, and the second counter is decremented instead.